# Finding roots of the equation $2 \sqrt[3]{2x-1}=x^3+1$,

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Equation is

$$2\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=x^3+1$$

I divided by $2$ and then cubed both sides,

$$2x-1=\frac{x^9+3x^6+3x^3+1}{8}$$

Now, if I make the substitution $y=x^3$ the equation becomes more complicated.

I need help to proceed from here. Thanks

Comment: You would then need to put $x=y^{1/3}$ into $2x=1$ portion, so yes would get more complicated/

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. By inspection, $x=1$ is a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite it as

$\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=\frac{x^3+1}{2}$

Now let $y=\sqrt[3]{2x-1}$

$y=\frac{x^3+1}{2}$

Now,

This can be rewritten as

$x=\sqrt[3]{2y-1}$

If $x=f(y)$, $y=f(x)$

We can conclude that

$$x=y$$

Now,

$$x^3-2x+1=0$$

And this cubic is easy

$$y=1,\frac{-1\pm 5}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You have obtained the equation
$$
x^9 + 3x^6 + 3x^3 - 16x + 9=0.
$$
By the rational root theorem we see that $x=1$ is a root. Furthermore we can factorize the equation as
$$
(x^6 + 2x^4 + 2x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x + 9)(x^2 + x - 1)(x - 1)=0
$$
and the polynomial of degree $6$ has no real roots (why?). So the only solutions are $x=1$ and the two solutions from the quadratic equation.

Comment: Why are there no roots for the sixth degree factor?

Comment: @Gkopi There are indeed six roots, but none of them is real. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374204/how-to-show-that-a-polynomial-does-not-have-real-roots).